# Async CTP + Postsharp

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, postsharp, async-ctp

Is there any restriction on the combination of the two frameworks? (in vs2012)

Searched and did not find any valid information. I can use async await, usually with PostSharp? I refer specifically to "OnMethodBoundaryAspect" and similar..

Comment: yes and it works! Actually I have not had time to update this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently works. 
Only is a necessary caution, because of the use of Task that are mentioned here:

http://theburningmonk.com/2012/11/aop-using-postsharp-attributes-with-async-tasktaskt-methods/